# How to set table caption at the top of a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, calendar, css-tables

I was trying to set calendar in table structure but I don't know how to set caption at the top of the table.

Also I can't change the table structure. I want it to look like below: [image]

```css
.calendar_wrap table {
    width: 100%;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar thead th {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #45515a;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tbody td {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #5b666f;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tfoot td a {
    color: #3d9596;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tbody td a {
    color: #EF9950;
}
.calender-box {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d9dd;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
caption {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #007ab0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="calendar_wrap mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-4 mt-4 calender-box">
        <table id="wp-calendar">
          <caption>February 2019</caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" title="Monday">M</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Tuesday">T</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Wednesday">W</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Thursday">T</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Friday">F</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Saturday">S</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Sunday">S</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2018/10/">« Oct</a></td>
              <td class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" class="pad">&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2019/02/14/" aria-label="Posts published on February 14, 2019">14</a></td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2019/02/18/" aria-label="Posts published on February 18, 2019">18</a></td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="today">25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td>
              <td class="pad" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</section>
```

Comment: just add ```caption-side: top;``` to your caption css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `caption-side: top` - for *style specificity* either make the selector `#wp-calendar caption` or add `!important` to the style - see demo below:

```css
.calendar_wrap table {
    width: 100%;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar thead th {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #45515a;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tbody td {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #5b666f;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tfoot td a {
    color: #3d9596;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.calendar_wrap #wp-calendar tbody td a {
    color: #EF9950;
}
.calender-box {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d9dd;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
caption {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #007ab0;
}

#wp-calendar caption { /* ADDED */
  caption-side: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="calendar_wrap mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-4 mt-4 calender-box">
        <table id="wp-calendar">
          <caption>February 2019</caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" title="Monday">M</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Tuesday">T</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Wednesday">W</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Thursday">T</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Friday">F</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Saturday">S</th>
              <th scope="col" title="Sunday">S</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2018/10/">« Oct</a></td>
              <td class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" class="pad">&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2019/02/14/" aria-label="Posts published on February 14, 2019">14</a></td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="//192.168.1.37:8000/silk-insurance/2019/02/18/" aria-label="Posts published on February 18, 2019">18</a></td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="today">25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td>
              <td class="pad" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</section>
```